PowerShell script to determine whether "this" computer is activated through Active Directory
I run a set of tools on Windows machines, both domain-joined and stand-alone. One of the tools involves offline activation using a CAC. I would like to write into my script a switch that will bypass that tool if the target machine is already activated through AD, and run it if not.
Is there a reliable place in WMI that will allow me to do this? Google AI search gave me this:
Get-WmiObject -Class SoftwareLicensingService | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ActivationMethod

but there is apparently no "ActivationMethod" property in SoftwareLicensingService.

You mean; "wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKeyDescription" ?

What I get from that is
ERROR:
Description = Invalid Query

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Sigshane, not sure whats wrong with your device, all my devices return proper reply of for example "OEM:DM", then i can see its method meaning at IE: https://www-eugenetoons-fr.translate.goog/licence-windows-compte-utilisateur-et-compte-microsoft/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp#les-quatre-types-de-licence-oem

Test this or some customized variation as it might work per quick Googling for you without the AI: https://www.ninjaone.com/script-hub/check-windows-activation-powershell/
